# Android Studio - compileOptions(ERROR: No signature of method: ...)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

https://developers.kakao.com/docs/latest/en/getting-started/sdk-android

I was doing configuration according to the contents of this page.

However, there was a problem with the code below.

```
android {

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

}
```

The code above spit out the error below.

```
No signature of method: build_2qf378v0zqbxe3d5cxom7rwd9.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_2qf378v0zqbxe3d5cxom7rwd9$_run_closure1) values: [build_2qf378v0zqbxe3d5cxom7rwd9$_run_closure1@6a47dac4]
```

In fact, there was a question with the same content as this question, but the answer is not good, so I'm asking this question.

Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of reason that you have it but in my case it was due ti incorrect way of signing keys.

Create a file called key.properties on adnroid root directory and add these on key.properties file.

```
storePassword=xxxx
keyPassword=xxxxxx
keyAlias=my
storeFile=/home/master/Android/signature/my.keystore
```

and remember to replace values with your values.

then Add these lines on build.gradle(app)

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
    def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
    if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
        keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
    }
```

and just replace your build type block

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

with this

```
signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
```

in your build.gradle(app) file.

This is the issue in my case. Will feel glad if it helps you too..

Happy coding...

Comment: `Could not get unknown property 'keystoreProperties' for SigningConfig$AgpDecorated_Decorated{name=release, storeFile=null, storePassword=null, keyAlias=null, keyPassword=null, storeType=pkcs12, v1SigningEnabled=true, v2SigningEnabled=true, enableV1Signing=null, enableV2Signing=null, enableV3Signing=null, enableV4Signing=null} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.SigningConfig$AgpDecorated`
The above error occurs.

Comment: Thanks for updating and sorry for the inconvenience. I have updated the answer as per your need. Please review it and accept if it solves your issue. Thanks